# "Wrong type argument: symbolp" on function usage

Tags: debugging

I am trying to use following code:

```
(defun rust-save-and-build (mode)
  (interactive)
  (save-buffer)

  (setq tmp (shell-command-to-string (format "cygpath.exe -m %s"
                     (buffer-file-name)))

(if (locate-dominating-file buffer-file-name "Cargo.toml")
        (compile mode)

  (compile
   (format "rustc %s %s.exe"
       tmp
       (file-name-sans-extension tmp))))))



(defun rust-cmd-run ()
  (interactive)
  (rust-save-and-build "cargo run"))

(defun rust-cmd-build ()
  (interactive)
  (rust-save-and-build "cargo build"))

(defun rust-cmd-test ()
  (interactive)
  (rust-save-and-build "cargo test"))



(add-hook 'rust-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (define-key rust-mode-map (kbd "<f5>") 'rust-cmd-run)))

(add-hook 'rust-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (define-key rust-mode-map (kbd "<f6>") 'rust-cmd-build)))

(add-hook 'rust-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (define-key rust-mode-map (kbd "<f7>") 'rust-cmd-test)))
```

but get "Wrong type argument: symbolp" error when use f-keys. The debug message is:

```
 Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument symbolp (if (locate-dominating-file buffer-file-name "Cargo.toml") (compile mode) (compile (format "rustc %s %s.exe" tmp (file-name-sans-extension tmp)))))
 (setq tmp (shell-command-to-string (format "cygpath.exe -m %s" (buffer-file-name))) (if (locate-dominating-file buffer-file-name "Cargo.toml") (compile mode) (compile (format "rustc %s %s.exe" tmp (file-name-sans-extension tmp)))))
  rust-save-and-build("cargo run")
  rust-cmd-run()
  call-interactively(rust-cmd-run nil nil)
  command-execute(rust-cmd-run)
```

**NB** that `rust-save-and-build` function works perfectly without argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indent your code properly and you will see that you did not close your `setq`:

```el
(defun rust-save-and-build (mode)
  (interactive)
  (save-buffer)

  (setq tmp (shell-command-to-string (format "cygpath.exe -m %s"
                                             (buffer-file-name)))

        (if (locate-dominating-file buffer-file-name "Cargo.toml")
            (compile mode)

          (compile
           (format "rustc %s %s.exe"
                   tmp
                   (file-name-sans-extension tmp))))))
```

You probably wanted something like this:

```el
(defun rust-save-and-build (mode)
  (interactive)
  (save-buffer)

  (setq tmp (shell-command-to-string (format "cygpath.exe -m %s"
                                             (buffer-file-name))))

  (if (locate-dominating-file buffer-file-name "Cargo.toml")
      (compile mode)

    (compile
     (format "rustc %s %s.exe"
             tmp
             (file-name-sans-extension tmp)))))
```

Remember that `show-paren-mode` is your friend, as are `TAB` and `C-M-q`. Get to know the keys bound in Emacs-Lisp mode - use `C-h m` and `C-h b` in a buffer with that mode. Or if you are doing this in another mode (e.g. in buffer `*scratch*`) then use them there, to the same effect.

Comment: Thank you! My fault. I though that setq creates namespace with variable. Many thanks for shortcuts.